# mysql relationships, make them optional?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, polymorphic-associations, erd

Hello I have the following mysql relationship,

[image]

As you can see the companies table has a 1:n relationship withe the members table. However this seems to implicit, meaning that when I try and save a member to my database they have to be associated with a company, or they insert does not happen.

Basically the architecture of our user signup process is that you can be an individual or sign as a company. How do I make my database design reflect this, so the relationship between the two tables is not a must.

Comment: Could you just make `companies_id` nullable, and `LEFT JOIN` to the `companies` table when you need to test whether they belong to a company?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a great design.

You should read up on the [Party Model](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471380237), and [Table Inheritance](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html) to see a design built to last. A skeleton:

```
PARTY
id

ORGANIZATION : PARTY
name
doing_business_as

INDIVIDUAL : PARTY
first_name
last_name

PARTY_RELATIONSHIP
from_party_id references party(id)
to_party_id references party(id)
from_date
to_date

ORGANIZATION_CONTACT_RELATIONSHIP : PARTY_RELATIONSHIP
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a contradiction between your schema and the actual business domain. If some users are NOT associated with a business, there's a 0:n relationship, not a 1:n relationship.

In practice, I've seen several ways of modelling this. The simplest, of course, is not to create the foreign key relationship - and that's what the business domain seems to suggest (individual users are not associated with companies).

If there is a substantial difference between "business" and "individual" customers, you might factor the distinct columns into separate tables - so you might have "users", and "business_users" where the business info lives (inc. the link to companies_id), and "individual_users", where the individual data lives.